# FileSystemWatcher stops monitoring network folder

Tags: windows, networking, c#-4.0, filesystemwatcher

I have developed file queue system, where several Apps from different Windows machines  watch the same mapped network drive for file changes and proceed files. To watch mapped drive for changes I use FileSystemWatcher (c# .NET 4.0) and everything works fine for ~one day after that FileSystemWatcher stops monitoring. I have tried to play with `FileSystemWatcher.Error` event to catch exceptions if any. Unfortunately **Error event is not always fired**. I do not find a way to solve the problem, FileSystemWatcher stops working and no error are throw. Any suggestion?

Comment: Don't make us guess at the errors that you *do* see.

Comment: The problem is that 50% of time Error event is not fired at all and here is the problem!

Comment: You are missing the point, the errors that you *do* see are no doubt relevant to why it is unreliable.  Right now, your question doesn't say anything more than 'it doesn't work right', nobody can help you with that.  Tell us what you *do* know, not what you don't know.

Answer (score 4):

`FileSystemWatcher` is NOT reliable for network drives... for example it is known to have some problems with SAMBA shares...

Another point is if you are using it in a Windows Service... trying to access a network drive from a Windows Service usually leads to some problem (depending on Windows version etc.).

Comment: I use it from console app and more I read about FileSystemWatcher more  your words sounds true. The main reason why I chose FileSystemWatcher because it is very fast, I do not find another way to build such fast File Queue. I have tried to use MSSQL as backend for queue and it is 6x slower.

Comment: I understand that but it is fast because it relies on some internal mechanisms in the filesystem implementation inside the OS... these are not reliable for network drives... I would make a central network share that is used by all workstations and run the FileSystemWatcher on the same system where the share resides...

Answer (score 1):

Networks gets disconnected. It's natural.

Have a look here: http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_general/eventsanddelegates/article.php/c9113

Good luck