# File Monitoring in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, filesystemwatcher

- We want to monitor File activity on one of the shared folders on our server.

  ```
  $folder = 'D:\MySharedFolder'
  ```
- Planning to use FileSystemWatcher and log the activities like New, Change & Delete to a text file.

  ```
  $fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property @{IncludeSubdirectories = $true;NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'}
  Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action 
  {
    $name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
    $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
    $timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated
    Write-Host "The file '$name' was $changeType at $timeStamp" -fore green
    Out-File -FilePath D:\Reports\Phx_New.txt -Append -InputObject "The file '$name' was $changeType at $timeStamp"
  }
  ```
- We want to run the monitoring between 0800 to 1800 (business hours)
- We want to break the monitoring log files, as file could get very huge if monitoring was left running all day saving to a single file.
- We plan to run it in 15 minutes interval, so in an hour's time I should get at least 4 log files.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is there an actual question in there?

Comment: Please keep in mind that attaching a FileSystemWatcher event on a network drive (i.e. SAMBA shares) can result in very unpredictable behavior, like the event disattaching whenever there is even a minimal network outage. I fought with it for days until I decided to give up and implement a files-loop script that runs every minute through Task Scheduler. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818545/filesystemwatcher-stops-monitoring-network-folder

Answer (score 0):

For that you can make another script with all the configurations you want and at the end just invoke this script to run on your configured intervals.